# Azure B2C: How do I get "group" claim in JWT token

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

In the Azure B2C, I used to be able to get a "groups" claim in my JWT tokens by following [Retrieving Azure AD Group information with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846446/retrieving-azure-ad-group-information-with-jwt):

- Open the old-school Azure manager (https://manage.windowsazure.com)
- Register my application with B2C
- Download the B2C manifest for the application
- In the manifest, change the "groupMembershipClaims" entry to

  > "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
- Upload the changed B2C manifest again

### The problem

This has worked well in the past (about a month ago, I believe...) but it doesn't anymore. See below for details...

### What I've tried sofar

#### Plan A: Use Azure Manager

Follow the known-good recipe above.

Unfortunately that doesn't work anymore - I get the following error when this client tries to authenticate me with B2C:

> AADB2C90068: The provided application with ID '032fe196-e17d-4287-9cfd-25386d49c0d5' is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again"

OK, fair enough - they're moving us to the new Portal.

#### Plan B: Use Azure Portal

Follow the good old recipe, using the new Portal.

But that doesn't work either - when I get to the "download manifest" part, I cannot find any way to access the manifest (and Googling tells me it's probably gone for good...).

#### Plan C: Mix Azure Portal and manager

Getting a little desperate, I tried mixing plans A and B: register the app using the new Portal, then change the manifest using the old Azure Manager.

But no luck - when I try to upload the manifest, it fails with the message

> ParameterValidationException=Invalid parameters provided; BadRequestException=Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.

#### Plan Z: Use the Graph API to retrieve group membership data

Just give up the "group" claim - instead, whenever I need group info, just query the B2C server using the Graph API.

I really, really don't want to do this - it would ruin the self-contained-ness of the access token, and make the system very "chatty".

But I've included it as a plan Z here, just to say: yes, I know the option exists, no I haven't tried it - and I'd prefer not to.

### The question:

How do I get the "group" claim in my JWT token these days?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plan Z it is I'm afraid. I don't know why they don't return it, but it's currently [marked as planned on their Feedback Portal (it's the highest rated item)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b).

This is how I'm doing it. Querying the groups when the user is authenticated, you can do it your way as well - just query as and when you need to. Depends on your use case.

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/unauthorised"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            CookieHttpOnly = true
        });

        // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(Globals.SignInPolicyId));
    }

    private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            MetadataAddress = string.Format(Globals.AadInstance, Globals.TenantName, policy),
            AuthenticationType = policy,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = Globals.ClientIdForLogin,
            RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                SecurityTokenValidated = SecurityTokenValidated
            },
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
            }
        };
    }

    private async Task SecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> token)
    {
            var groups = await _metaDataService.GetGroups(token.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value);

            if (groups?.Value != null && groups.Value.Any())
            {
                foreach (IGroup group in groups.Value.ToList())
                {
                    token.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, group.DisplayName, ClaimValueTypes.String, "GRAPH"));
                }
            }
    }

    // Used for avoiding yellow-screen-of-death
    private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();

        if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

My `GetGroups` method just queries the [`getMemberGroups` method on the Users API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups)

Then I have a simple helper method to determine whether the user is in a role:

```cs
public static bool UserIsInRole(IPrincipal user, string roleName)
{
    var claims = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    if (claims == null) return false;

    return claims.FindAll(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Any(x => x.Value == roleName);
}
```

Comment: [seems like the same question/issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885795/azure-ad-b2c-role-management)

Comment: This answer seems woefully incomplete.  I don't understand the six upvotes, so I'm missing something obvious.  What is _metaDataService?  What URL do you connect to?  Where is the code for the 'GetGroups' (which seems to be critical to understanding this answer)?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c