# asp net core 2 and Azure AD B2C, adding group based authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm creating an asp net core 2 web api using azure AD B2C for authentification.
I would like to use AD B2C groups to restrict the use of some controllers to admin members.

I've understood that for the moment the only way to achieve that is to access graph api and add to user's claims some role claims.

But I'm having troubles querying graph api in my startup.

My `ConfigureService` method looks like this :

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
            .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                options.Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/", "b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com", "B2C_1_DefaultSignUpIn");
                options.Audience = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                };
            })
       .AddCookie(options =>
       {
           options.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";
           options.LogoutPath = "/Account/SignOut";
           options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
           options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
           {
               OnRedirectToLogin = OnRedirectToLogin
           };
       });
```

and the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` looks like this :

```cs
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.TokenValidatedContext ctx)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var oidClaim = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oidClaim?.Value))
        {
            var users = aadClient.Users;
            var pagedCollection = await this.aadClient.Users.GetByObjectId(oidClaim.Value).MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();

            do
            {
                var directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
                foreach (var directoryObject in directoryObjects)
                {
                    var group = directoryObject as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;
                    if (group != null)
                    {
                        ((ClaimsIdentity)ctx.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, group.DisplayName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
                    }
                }
                pagedCollection = pagedCollection.MorePagesAvailable ? await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync() : null;
            }
            while (pagedCollection != null);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm having a failure on the following line :

```cs
var pagedCollection = await 
 this.aadClient.Users.GetByObjectId(oidClaim.Value).MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();
```

the exception is `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Secure binary serialization is not supported on this platform.`

I'm guessing that this is a restriction of asp net core but I cannot figure how to setup a workaround for this.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Have you seen this SO post: [Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)?

Comment: And this one: [Azure AD B2C - Role management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885795/azure-ad-b2c-role-management)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorize By Group in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302231/authorize-by-group-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)