# ASP.Net Core Identity Combination of AAD-B2C with custom role store

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-identity

I am developing a ASP.Net Core Web app with an AAD-B2C as LogIn-Provider. So users have to log in first to access the site --> **Authentication**.

Then, I want to evaluate what the user actually is allowed to access --> **Authorization**

I have a requirement that RBAC is used and the roles are handled NOT in any kind of AD, but in our own database which again is behind a REST API. So I went with my custom implementation of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserRoleStore<MyUser>` to retrieve my users and roles from my REST API and registered that in `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>();
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<MyUser>, MyUserStore>();
services.AddTransient<IUserRoleStore<MyUser>, MyUserStore>();
```

But now the default Authentication does not seem to work anymore (as `MyUser` is totally different from the ASP.Net default `User`, e.g. `MyUser` does not have `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`). Also I can't see the site ever calling `MyUserStore.IsInRoleAsync` when I added a Razor directive like `User.IsInRole("Admin")`.

Am I missing something ? Is is not possible to "split" ASP.Net Core Identity to handle Authentication one way (AAD-B2C) and Authorization another way (custom Store) at the same time? Or am I just calling it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure AD B2C you need to have custom roles defined within your Azure AD and I am fairly certain that the situation you are describing is not supported. B2C does not include group claims in the token it sends to the application but some workarounds are suggested here. [Azure AD B2C - Role management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885795/azure-ad-b2c-role-management)

Comment: I don't try to get group claims from **AAD-B2C**. I only want to verify the user's identity (UPN).
Then, I want to look up the user in my own database where I also store my own roles and the user-role associations. These roles shall then determine the user's authorizations, in a best case via **ASP.Net Core Identity** so I can use existing calls and annotations (i.e. `User.IsInRole("Admin")` to show or hide certain UI elements).