# How to hook into AuthorizationCodeReceived when using AddAzureADB2C?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I've created a simple Blazor server application linking to an Azure B2C directory for authorization.
Everything works but I need to add additional role claims to the token.  Research has pointed me to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885795/azure-ad-b2c-role-management) which refers to adding the claims during the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification([Example here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L155)).

I understand what I need to do, but the example is using *OpenIdConnectAuthentication* (from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`) instead of Blazor server's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI`.

How can I still access and amend the claims in the token once it's received? Is such a thing supported in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI` or should be switching to OpenId?

Below is the boilerplate included in a basic Blazor server application but the `AzureADB2COptions` are all just string config values.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(o =>
        {
            if (_environment.IsDevelopment()) //only add details when debugging
            {
                o.DetailedErrors = true;
            }
        });

        // remaining service configuration
    }
```

Comment: Related question + answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488529/azureadb2c-ui-access-to-openidconnectevents-ontokenvalidated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override the specific schema after `AddAzureADB2C` , then register your events like :

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {



        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived= async ctx =>
        {


            .....
        },
    };
});
```

Use `options.ResponseType = "code"` to triage the access token exchange otherwise `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` won't fire ,  you can follow the code sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L63) , that code sample doesn't directly use the library , but has the same logic as  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI1`

Comment: Thanks for this! I've basically come to the realization that I'm going about this in the wrong way (ie "code flow" is not what I should be using) and your answer led me to that.