# AzureADB2C.UI - access to OpenIdConnectEvents (OnTokenValidated)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, claims

I use the library [AzureADB2C.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI) to enable Azure ADB2C authentication.

But now I would like to add a custom claim after authentication and I wanted to do this during OpenIdConnectEvents.OnTokenValidated. But those events are not exposed.

Any suggestion what the most appropriate way is to add a custom claim in this situation? And preferable keep on using the package to avoid too much custom code. I tried the [following on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664401/how-to-hook-into-authorizationcodereceived-when-using-addazureadb2c) but this didn't work out.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to below code sample to add claims into user's principle  :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {

        OnTokenValidated =  ctx =>
        {
            //query the user's groups using api 

            // add claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("groups", xxxx-xx-xx)
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },   
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! So setting the ResponseType in the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664401/how-to-hook-into-authorizationcodereceived-when-using-addazureadb2c breaks this. I'll dive a bit deeper to try to understand this. Thanks again.

Comment: i accidentally had `AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` twice instead of `OpenIdScheme`