# Restrict Access to a Web site / app using B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to allow or restrict clients to authenticate first with B2C to access to certain portion or feature of a web site or app? As per the client:[image: Client's target]

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to control the permissions of Azure AD B2C users.

You can look into [directory extension optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-directory-extension-optional-claims). Configure custom claims for the users and get the claims from the token. A simple way with Powershell cmd can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/61117/azure-b2c-approles-and-permissions.html?sort=votes).

Another method is to manually retrieve the group claims and inject them into the token. Detailed steps are listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885795/azure-ad-b2c-role-management?answertab=votes#tab-top).

You can set the corresponding permissions according to the user's custom claim or groups.