# How to do Blazor server side web app with azure ADB2C authentication and role based autherization

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-ad-b2c, roles, blazor-server-side

I would like to setup an Blazor server side application (NET5) and I already use the **azure AD B2C authentication** and it works fine. Now I would like to add **role based autherization** and don't know how to do it in the best way.

As far as I know, azure ADB2C doesn't support **roles** out of the box. I would be fine with storing the users and roles data in seperate sql database in Azure with tables like AspNetUsers and aspNetUserRoles etc. I need a database for my app anyway. I'm wondering how I connect the  **autherization attribute** to this database without damaging the connection to **azure ADB2C connetion for authentication**.

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better one? If possible, I would like to keep the ADB2C authentication part.

Thanks for your help and ideas.
Jörg

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea with sql database, but there is a workaround using [**custom attribute**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow#use-a-custom-attribute-in-your-user-flow). For example, create a custom attribute named `AADRole`. Assign a value（which means its role access to certain apps）to different users and then get the claim from id token after B2C users sign in. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719116/how-to-set-information-to-azure-ad-b2c-users-after-registration?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more details.

There is an issue: [How to Use Role-Based Authorization with .NET Core [Authorize]](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/35120/view.html).