# Should I migrate complete user store (AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, etc) to Azure AD B2C? Is this a standard practice?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c, azure-migrate

I have a MVC application and a mobile application which uses Asp.Net Identity for user management and for managing their roles. I'm trying to migrate all the user from our SQL database to Azure AD B2C. I have written a script which will read the users from existing SQL database table (AspNetUsers) to Azure AD B2C via Microsoft Graph API. I'm not sure whether all the attributes from all the Identity tables (AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, etc) will be moved to Azure AD B2C? Is this a standard practice? If yes, are we going to keep all these attributes via custom user attributes? Or, we need to create different groups in Azure AD B2C and then manage their roles via Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Identity tables (AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, etc) won't be moved to B2C.

If you need these data (usually we need roles) and you are using built-in user flow, it's recommended to use custom attributes.

Group claim is also supported in this case if you are using custom policy.

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719116/how-to-set-information-to-azure-ad-b2c-users-after-registration?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more details.