# .net core 2.0 single sign on with Azure - Active Directory Group Listing

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, active-directory, openid

Currently using .net core 2.0, OpenIDConnect Single Sign On with Azure AD.  Trying to retrieve a list of the the Azure AD Groups assigned to the logged on user but am coming up blank.   When looping through the claims on the User object, I don not see anything for groups ...

```
            var claims = User.Claims.Select(c =>
            new{
                Type = c.Type,
                Value = c.Value
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Azure AD Group information with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846446/retrieving-azure-ad-group-information-with-jwt)

Comment: TL;DR from other question, set `groupMembershipClaims` to *"All"* or *"SecurityGroup"* in your app manifest in Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my issue was not code related ... I need to edit the Manifest file for my App Registration in Azure to set groupMembershipClaims = "All".  After setting the groups scope on OpenIDCOnnect, I was able to access all of my Active Directory Groups via the User.Claims listing where type = "groups"